# ¿Cómo se pueden guardar los resultados de una SELECT en una variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server

estoy con SQL Server y necesito que los resultados de una select se guarden en una variable y no tengo ni idea de cómo hacerlo.
He pensado en algo como esto

```
DECLARE nombreVariable 
INSERT INTO nombreVariable 
SELECT campoQueQuiero FROM miTabla
SELECT nombreVariable
```

¿Me podéis echar una mano?

Answer (score 3):

Estabas cerca.

Puedes declarar, asignarle un valor genérico y guardar el valor del campo de la siguiente forma:

```
DECLARE @var1 varchar(30);         
SELECT @var1 = 'Generic Name';         
SELECT @var1 = Name         
FROM Sales.Store         
WHERE CustomerID = 1000 ;        
SELECT @var1 AS 'Company Name';
```

Puedes además obtener distintas columnas de la tablas en distintas variables:

```
DECLARE @var1 varchar(30);    
DECLARE @var2 varchar(30);        
SELECT @var1 = 'Generic Name 1';    
SELECT @var2 = 'Generic Name 2';         
SELECT @var1 = Name, @var2 = Descrip         
FROM Sales.Store         
WHERE CustomerID = 1000 ;        
SELECT @var1 AS 'Company Name', @var2 AS 'Company description';
```

[Fuente](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1):

Con la siguiente línea asignas el campo que obtienes de tu tabla a la variable que acabas de declarar:

```
SELECT @nombreVariable = campoQueQuiero FROM miTabla
```

> Recuerda que la consulta puede devolver una o varias filas, debes construir una consulta SELECT que devuelva una sola fila para que esto funcione.