# ¿Cómo almacenar valores de una consulta en una variable sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo una consulta,  almaceno sus resultados en una tabla temporal(devuelve lista de sucursales:
 "1, 2, 3, 4, 5"), tengo una variable en la cual quiero almacenar ese resultado.

```
       select suc_id 
       into #sucursales_temp
       from t_suc_cons


      DECLARE
      @vs_lista --varchar(80)

      select @vs_lista = sucr_id 
      from #sucursales_temp
```

Necesito ésta variable para otra validación en la que compararé con los valores mediante "IN"

```
        UPDATE t_cit SET suc_id = @vs_suc, usuario_modi = @vs_usuario, fecha_modif = GETDATE()  where cit = @vs_c and suc_id IN (@vs_lista)
```

Ésto es lo que intentado pero me muestra error.

```
"Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Procedure usp_suc, Line 285 Must declare the scalar variable "@vs_lista"."
```

Si alguien puede ayudarme se lo agradecería mucho.

Saludos.

Comment: Posible duplicado [¿Cómo se pueden guardar los resultados de una SELECT en una variable?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/156166/69447)

Comment: Uno de los problemas lo tienes aquí: `DECLARE  @vs_lista --varchar(80)`, en todo caso descomenta el tipo. Pero más allá de eso, te  sugiero que el `where` lo indiques así: `suc_id IN (select sucr_id from #sucursales_temp)` y te evitas el problema de usar variables ya que tal como lo estás usando no funcionaría.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo se pueden guardar los resultados de una SELECT en una variable?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/156166/c%c3%b3mo-se-pueden-guardar-los-resultados-de-una-select-en-una-variable)

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo haria de la siguiente manera:

```
   select suc_id 
   into #sucursales_temp
   from t_suc_cons

  --Declaro la variable de tipo nvarchar(max)
  DECLARE @vs_lista nvarchar(max) --varchar(80)

  --En el select le voy agregando el valor anterior.
  select @vs_lista = @vs_lista + ',' + sucr_id 
  from #sucursales_temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví de ésta manera, por si a alguien le sirve algún día.

```
   select suc_id 
   into #sucursales_temp
   from t_suc_cons


    UPDATE t_cit SET suc_id = @vs_suc, usuario_modi = @vs_usuario, fecha_modif = GETDATE()  where cit = @vs_c and suc_id IN (Select suc_id from #sucursales_temp)
```